# Can I replace Affx- with rs in text file in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have a huge text file. I want to replace all strings that start with `Affx-` and then some numbers (like `Affx-74537382` or `Affx-4374575`) with `rs` (and the same numbers like: `rs74537382` or `rs4374575`. Is this possible with `sed -i 's/Affx-/rs/` ?

Since the file is so huge I am not sure how to verify that the command is working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -E 's/^Affx(-[0-9]+)/rs\1/' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

*Details*:

- `-E` - POSIX ERE syntax enabled
- `^` - start of string
- `Affx` - a literal text
- `(-[0-9]+)` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to the value in this group): `-` and one or more digits.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/tkeYlk):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='Blah-1233455
Affx-74537382
Some line here
Affx-4374575
End of text 123456778.'

sed -E 's/^Affx(-[0-9]+)/rs\1/' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
Blah-1233455
rs-74537382
Some line here
rs-4374575
End of text 123456778.
```